# Run command after gem install from gem root folder

Tags: ruby, deployment, rubygems, chef-infra

I'm deploying a Sinatra app as a gem. I have a command that starts the app as a service. 
We are using chef to manage our deployments.

How can I run the command to start the app service but only after it's fully installed (including run-time dependencies)?

I've tried Googling for trying to run a post-install script but I haven't found anything that is of use or concrete without some complicated 'extconf.rb' work around

I would prefer not to use an execute resource if I can help it.

EDIT: I tried what was suggested but it breaks thins in way that causes berkshelf not to work in our pipeline.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
execute "run-service:post_install" do
    cwd  (f = File.expand_path(__FILE__).split('/')).shift(f.length - 3).join('\\')
    timeout 5
    command "bundle && rake service:post_install"
    # action :nothing
    # subscribes :run, "gem_package[gem_name]" , :delayed
end
```

It doesn't matter if I un-comment or not the last two lines, it just breaks things but if i take out the whole thing it stops breaking things. Obviously I'm doing something wrong but I'm not sure what.

EDIT:
IT's the command itself that breaks it, when I change command to `ls` and `action` to `:run`, it breaks.

EDIT:after changing the command path around a bit I managed to get it to spit out a usable error, it was trying to run the command from chef cook books path, so I've (hopefully) forced it to use the correct path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, In the end I decided to try using the service resource because it allows you to set start, and stop commands.

The code that I used is :

```
service service_name do
  init_command ("#{%x(gem env gemdir).strip.gsub('/','\\')}\\gems\\gem_name-#{installing_version}")
  start_command "rake service:start"
  stop_command "rake service:stop"
  reload_command "rake service:reload"
  restart_command "rake service:restart"
  supports start: true, restart: true, reload: true
  action [:enable,:start]
end
```

I'm still having problems but this is of a different sort.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you not want to use an execute resource? That is exactly what it is for, running commands from Chef. Chef obeys the order of the resources, so if you have a `gem_package` followed by an `execute` they will run in that order.

Comment: because It needs to be idempotent and execute aren't really idempotent unless you use an `if` check and I'm not sure why but something about that makes me not like it because of that. Yes I'm aware, that's not very logical but there has to be a more self contained (as in the application runs itself after install rather then from outside) way to do it.

Comment: You can use a notification from the gem_package resource if you only want to run the command when the state of the gem changes (like going from not installed to installed).